# docker overlay for local development and remote containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, docker-network

I am looking to improve our development cycle, using multiple docker containers, used by multiple dev teams

Currently each dev team is responsible of few services, that are dependant on other teams services. Meaning all dev teams need to run all containers locally

What i'm trying to figure out is how can a local container be exposed to a remote network on a remote cluster, that each team will join its network, without the need of running all the services locally

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is using ssh tunnel sharing the docker.sock file => registered services will be exposed to other machines

```
ssh -nNT -L /tmp/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  <USER>@<IP> &
```

and

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///tmp/docker.sock
```